# Debian packaging: reorder dh_installinit and dh_ucf

Tags: package, debian, packaging

I have a simple Debian package that uses the **debian/*package*.init** and  **debian/*package*.default** to install init scripts, and **debian/*package*.ucf** to provide (template) config files.

I don't have any overrides in **debian/rules** and when installing/upgrading the package the procedure follows this order:

- service is stopped
- package is installed/upgraded
- service started
- UCF invoked

My problem is that if the conf-files are still the default ones that came with the package, they get updated (all good) but then a manual restart/reload of the service is needed to read the new config files.

Is there some **debian/rules** magic I can invoke to delay the starting of the service until after UCF as (potentially) copied new config files into /etc ?

Many thanks,

Comment: The behavior you are observing is clearly a bug. You should report it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to invoke dh_* scrips in different order? For example, something like this in `debian/rules`:

```
override_dh_installinit:
    echo "dh_installinit is delayed until dh_ucf is run"

override_dh_ucf:
    dh_ucf $@
    dh_installinit $@
```

This could possibly reorder code snippets genedated by debhelper that will result in desired behaviour.